# Component cannot access to data that starts with $

Tags: vue.js

I made some components with mixins.

> mixin1.vue

```js
export default {
  data(){
     return {
      $_mixin1_data1 : 'data1',
      data2 : 'data2'
     }
  },
  methods:{
    $_mixin1_method1(){
    
    }
  }
}
```

> Parent.vue

```js
import mixin1 from './mixin1';

export default {
  name : 'Parent',
  mixins:[mixin1],
  data(){
    return {
      parent1 : 'parent1'
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    console.log(this.parent1); // parent1
    console.log(this.$_mixin1_data1) //undefined
    console.log(this.data2); //data2
  }
}
```

When I use Parent component with mixin1 component, Parent component could not find data that starts with $*. But "data2" data and the method that starts with $* is worked. I don't know why the data that starts with $_ isn't detected. I might not understand Vue's concept.
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Not sure exactly where this is written in the documentation, but `$` is a reserved thing, so starting with it is probably what's causing the issue here. Couldn't you name it in another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#declaring-reactive-state)

> Vue uses a `$` prefix when exposing its own built-in APIs via the component instance. It also reserves the prefix `_` for internal properties. You should avoid using names for top-level `data` properties that start with either of these characters.